# How to calculate the unknown vector when the distance between vectors are known?

Tags: vectors

$‖C-P‖=d$
Consider the above equation where $C$ and $P$ are two vectors.$C=(X,Y,Z)$ and $P=(U,V,W)$. $d$ is the distance between two vectors ($C$ and $P$). I know the vector $P=(U,V,W)$ and the distance between two vectors '$d$'. Now how to calculate the unknown vector $C=(X,Y,Z)$?

Comment: There will be infinitely many vectors $C$ which are a distance $d$ from $P$.  They will all lie on the surface of a sphere, of radius $d$, centered at the point $P$.  You will need to provide additional conditions to be able to say that one of these vectors is the "best" vector and call it $C$.  Alternatively, if any of these vectors will do, simply add $d$ to one of the components of $P$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @GingerBreadMan Lets say I know only C vector which is at a distance of 'd' from vector P. Now, how do I mathematically calculate the C ?

Comment: If you knew $C$, why would you need to calculate it?
If you want a $C$ that will work, try $P + (d,0,0)$.

Comment: @GingerBreadMan What I mean is I know only P vector values and the distance between P and C which is d. Now I want to calculate vector C which is camera center using these.

Comment: Please update your question to include additional context.  Feel free to include information about the real world application.  Without that additional context, your question is incomplete.  As it stands, I can provide an infinite number of answers, and all of them will be correct.  A picture might help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no such thing as "distance between 2 vectors", any 2 vectors can be drawn from 1 initial point (say the origin) because as long as you maintain the magnitude, direction, and sense of a vector then you can move it where ever you want.

So $\|C-P\|$ actually the length of the vector $\vec a$ that is defined by $\vec a= \vec C-\vec P$

Now if you have $P(U,V,W)$ and you want to get the vector $C$ (that is not unique) you can simply consider it as $C(U+d,V,W)$.